# ClassNotFoundException for hadoop custom input format in amzon EMR

Tags: json, hadoop, emr

Getting ClassNotFoundException when I use the custom input format for mapreduce in hadopp using amazon EMR. The json.org dependency is present in maven pom.xml and still it throws error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at ERMHadoop.mywebapp.jsonFeed.JsonInputFormat.createRecordReader(JsonInputFormat.java:41)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:738)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)


java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 255.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)
```

Comment: Are you using the maven assembly plugin to build a jar-with-dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the difference between assembly plugin and normal maven. here is my pom.xml with dependencies

Comment: I'm not sure what is the difference between assembly plugin and normal maven. Yes, I'm using dependencies in pom.xml to create the custom jar for emr. here is my json dependency in pom.xml

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20131018</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: See this other related question for what i'm referring too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300070/package-a-multiple-entry-jar-using-maven-for-hadoop-project

Comment: I'm not looking for multi entry jar, I'm getting ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException though the json jar is present in my manifest below:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: YC31RS2
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_39
Main-Class: ERMHadoop.mywebapp.jsonFeed.FeedDriver
Class-Path: commons-lang-2.3.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar slf4j-api-1.7
 .5.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar json-20131018.jar json-simple-1.1.jar jettiso
 n-1.0-alpha-1.jar stax-api-1.0.1.jar

Comment: Present in the manifest yes, but is the json-simple jar present in the jar too, or on the distributed classpath? you're problem relates to a map task not being able to find this class at runtime

Comment: Note that you can use "jar tf  JAR_FILE | grep ClassName" to make sure that the JAR_FILE actually contains your class. Also make sure you did not forget to specify jar to push to your Hadoop cluster. It can be done by setJarByCass of your JobConf